# CakePHP version 4 create folder if not exist

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have seen cakephp documentation they have [File& Folder](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html) class. They declared this class has deprecated.

Now `mkdir()` is it the best way to create folder in cakephp version 4 ?

```
if (!is_dir('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

Is it enough or has there best way ?

Comment: yes, for creating thats enough.